# How to only join lines that start with multiple spaces

Tags: replace, original-vim, join

what is the global command that will join lines that start with more than one space?

I have tried this but it does not work as expected:

```
:g/ \{2,}//J
```

Example:

I want to turn this:

```
01:001:001 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
01:001:002 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was
           upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon
           the face of the waters.
01:001:003 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.
01:001:004 And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the
           light from the darkness.
01:001:005 And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called
           Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day.
01:001:006 And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the
           waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters.
01:001:007 And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were
           under the firmament from the waters which were above the
           firmament: and it was so.
01:001:008 And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the
           morning were the second day.
01:001:009 And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered
           together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it
           was so.
```

Into this:

```
01:001:001 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
01:001:002 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the
Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
01:001:003 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.
01:001:004 And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.
01:001:005 And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the mornin
g were the first day.
01:001:006 And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the water
s from the waters.
01:001:007 And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the wat
ers which were above the firmament: and it was so.
01:001:008 And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day.
01:001:009 And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the
 dry land appear: and it was so.
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out since I need to join current line to above line and not the below line to the current line, -j has to be used like so:

```
:g/ \{2,}/-j
```

Comment: Good job. However, though it works fine for your example it would break if you had 2+ spaces in the interior of a non-indented line. Therefore, a "more correct" and more generally usable answer would have a "start of line" anchor at the beginning of the pattern: `:g/^ \{2,}/-j`.